# Spring simultaneous calls

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, thread-safety

I think my problems is architecture-based, but not so sure so I'll try to explain the reality of it.

The software I'm working on is monolithic oriented but fully exposed with SOAP. The architecture is as followed :

- The fondamental concept is what we called "**Transaction**", which is defined by its request and response (used for SOAP). It structures configurable business logic as well (editing documents, workflows, etc)
- We have 1 bean configured in application-context.xml for each Transaction (PersonViewTransaction, PersonSelectTransaction, PersonEditTransaction for example)
- All of them inherit

  - from the same **abstract class AbstractTransaction** which implements controls on the request provided
  - that AbstractTransaction implements an interface ITransaction
- We build a TransactionFactory which, on any call with beanId and request, calls static methods calling every ITransaction's methods for the Transaction identified by beanId.

When a call is made through Webservices, a Servlet will call this factory, and execute the same logic, as a call from the web project (maven) would do calling directly the factory.

In other words :

#### Definition of ITransaction

```
/**
 * The main interface defining what a transaction is.
 */
public interface ITransaction <Q extends GenericRequest, P extends GenericResponse> {

    P businessLogic(Q req);

    void executeControls(String transactionId, Q params, PerimetreAppel environnement)

    default void controleLicence() throws NassurCoreException
    {
        //TODO : contrôles de la licence à effectuer.
    }

    /**
     * Log before transaction
     */
    default void logEntree() throws NassurCoreException
    {
        //TODO to be implemented
    }

    /**
     * Log after transaction
     */
    default void logSortie() throws NassurCoreException
    {
        //TODO  to be implemented
    }

    /**
     * Checks that the user can call transaction
     */
    default void controleDroits() throws NassurCoreException
    {
        //TODO to be implemented
    }


    //...
    //Some other method not necessarily implemented in each transaction
}


/**
 * The abstract defining the default behaviour of a transaction
 */
public abstract class AbstractTransaction<Q extends GenericRequest, P extends GenericResponse> implements ITransaction<Q, P>{

    @Autowired
    private ControlService controlService;

    //.... some other autowired fields

    @Autowired
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    protected String idTransaction;

    //Every transaction  must implement its own logic
    P businessLogic(Q params);


    @Override
    public void initialisation(String trId) 
    {
        this.idTransaction = trId;
    }


    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void executeControls(String transactionId, Q params, PerimetreAppel environnement)
    {
        //Some controls found from database, and executed 
        // A control consists of a combination between java checks and some Jruby executed from the Service
        List<SomeEntity> list = someEntityRepository.findByTransactionId(transactionId);
        for(SomeEntity  e : list){
            controlService.executeUnitControl(e, params);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Transactions

```
//Example Transaction
public class PersonViewTransaction extends AbstractTransaction<PersonViewRequest, PersonViewResponse>{

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public PersonViewResponse businessLogic(PersonViewRequest req){
        //...
    }
}


//Example Transaction
public class PersonEditTransaction extends AbstractTransaction<PersonEditRequest, PersonEditResponse> {

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public PersonEditResponse businessLogic(PersonEditRequest req){
        //...
    }
}


//Example Transaction
public class PersonSearchTransaction extends AbstractTransaction<PersonSearchRequest, PersonSearchResponse> {

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public PersonSearchResponse businessLogic(PersonSearchRequest req){
        //...
    }
}
```

Those Beans are declared in application-context.xml.

#### Factory

```
public class TransactionFactory
{
    public static GenericResponse executeTransaction(String id, GenericRequest req, HttpServletRequest request)
                    throws SomeExceptions
    {
        ServletContext servletCtx = request.getSession().getServletContext();
        ApplicationContext actualCtx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletCtx);

        ITransaction tr = (ITransaction<GenericRequest, GenericResponse>) actualCtx.getBean(id.name());

        if (tr == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("internal Error", null);
        }
        return executeStack(id, tr, req, request);
    }



    private static GenericResponse executeStack(String id, ITransaction tr, GenericRequest req, HttpServletRequest request)
                    throws SomeExceptions
    {
        try
        {
            tr.initialisation(id);
            tr.controleLicence();
            tr.logEntree();
            tr.controleDroits();
            //...Several operations calling ITransaction

            tr.executeControls(id, req, provenance);

            //Calling transaction logic
            GenericResponse resp = tr.businessLogic(req);

            //...Many "after-business" other calls

            return resp;

        }
        catch (SomeExceptions e)
        {
            logger.error(e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

By some mystery, when two calls are made simultaneously on the same transactionId, the `executeControls` throws some weird returns, as if both executions where mixed in the same bean (to me it appears thread-safe but not that sure...) :

```
List<SomeEntity> list = someEntityRepository.findByTransactionId(transactionId);
for(SomeEntity  e : list){
    controlService.executeUnitControl(e, params);
}
```

`executeUnitControl` checks if the control must apply, and throws an error if needed. To be more into detail, this is based on a JRuby script that takes params as parameter to build configurable and non-Java based business logic.

Thanks a lots for your help, and if there are french people, I'd love to chat with them any time to explain more details if needed !

Comment: *as if both executions where mixed in the same bean*: that's exactly what happens. Spring beans are singletons (by default). They must be thread-safe, because they **are** called concurrently.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What makes it not thread safe ? since I use all methods only with arguments / returns and no field in the beans, I'd guess it's thread safe by nature... I might misunderstand this.
Would making the bean scope "prototype" enough ? (I'd guess the factory would call getBean(beanId) and instantiate it, based on what I found in the doc, but not 100% sure)

Comment: If your beans are stateless, then yes, they are thread-safe. The fact that you call several methods of tr in sequence and don't have any return value for any of these method calls, makes me *guess* that this tr bean is stateful, but I have no idea since I can't see its code. And the problem ("throws some weird returns") is much too vague, especially without seeing the code, to be actionable.

Comment: Thanks. I think they are. Can it be the fact that I have and abstract class defining all default behaviours that all singletons inherit ?

Comment: They are not stateless: `this.idTransaction = trId;` This mutates the state of the singleton bean. Your factory wouldn't compile: there is no name() method in String.

Comment: There is no name() method in String : Yes, that's because it's originally an enum, and I simplified it.

Comment: This mutates the state of the singleton bean : Okay I get it ! The state is properly defined and not just a code convention. I better understand this now, I think. 
I'll test this.
Would you have any resource regarding that ? 
Also, can   @Autowired fields  alter the state of the singleton ?

Comment: No. Autowiring is done once, at startup, before the bean can be used.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Actually all of theses checks lead me into dealing with the Jruby script engine, that is not thread safe by default, so that lead to really weird errors since it was called many times by different thread. I opened an other issue for that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51420791/new-jruby-binding-vs-org-jruby-embed-localcontext-scope-threadsafe
Thanks again !